# Split a string using a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split the following str into an array that has 2 elements, the first being 'Some words in a sentence', the second being 'ABC' where ABC can be any upper case character.

```
const str = 'Some words in a sentence (ABC)';
const regex = ?
const arr = str.split(regex);
...
expect(arr[0]).to.eq('Some words in a sentence');
expect(arr[1]).to.eq('ABC');
expect(arr.length).to.eq(2);
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: I don't think you can get that result with a simple split, you'd get an extra empty string element when splitting around `[()]`

Comment: Wow, all I'm asking for is peoples "thoughts" not code. I thought this was a good place to ask questions - clearly not :-(

Answer (score 2):

The trick with regex is to break it into steps.

- You want two elements, that means two groups, e.g. `(<-- between these -->)`)
- The easy one is getting the (ABC) at the end -> `\((.*?)\)$` (escaped ()'s
- And now you can conclude the rest is the other part: `(.*?)`

<sub>Explained:</sub>

```
                          /---\   is the \((.*?)\)$
 Some words in a sentence (ABC)
 ^----      (.*?)    ----^
```

That should push you in the direction you are looking for, the final part is for you to figure out :)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Goto  https://regex101.com/ and try this

`/(.*)\(([A-Z]{3})\)`/

with your string

```
'Some words in a sentence (ABC)'
```

You will get

```
Match 1
Full match  0-30    `Some words in a sentence (ABC)`
Group 1.    0-25    `Some words in a sentence `
Group 2.    26-29   `ABC`
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, much appreciated.